# Dell XPS 13 9333, touchpad not working with kernel 3.16 in Utopic Unicorn

Tags: kernel, dell, touchpad

So I upgraded today my distribution, from 14.04 Trusty Thar to 14.10 Utopic Unicorn.

I had issues with the touchpad on 14.04 (jumping cursor while typing stuff) and the Synaptics upstream driver with kernel 3.16.x was supposed to fix it, according to several websites.

Yet after I restarded my Dell XPS 13, the issue is worst: now I just don't have any cursor anymore on screen. I must use the keyboard shortcuts for every "move" I want to do on my desktop and inside each apps.

I relogged with XFCE as a backup, instead of Unity, the trouble is different: I can see the cursor, it moves more or less according to my fingers on the touchpad, but it seems to click everywhere during the process, and sometimes it disappears too. Weird stuff.

I already tried to "apt-get purge" the synaptics driver, and re-install it, didn't work.

Right now while starting the computer, I must press "Escape" to enter Grub2 and choose the "old" kernel 3.13.x instead of 3.16.x, and I'm back with a enabled touchpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249625
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf did the job

Comment: Thanks, it working well :)

I'm not sure yet for the "jumping cursor" bug that spoiled the experience in 14.04, but first minutes typing stuff while I booted with 3.16 kernel, it feels less hazardous already.